# Opensearch query error: Fielddata is not supported on field [x] of type [search_as_you_type]

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I am running the below query against my sales order index:

```
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"range":{"created":{"gte":"2023-10-23T20:10:23","lte":"2023-12-23T20:10:23"}}},{"term":{"orderStatus.keyword":{"value":"ACC_ERROR"}}}]}}}
```

And getting the following error, which contains a field I'm not using in my query?

***Fielddata is not supported on field [orderReference] of type [search_as_you_type]***

I'm unclear why I'm getting an error on a field that's not even in my query? THis error is returned from the opensearch .net client. If I run the query directly using Opensearch API, I just get back:

```
    {

  "took": 7,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 0,
    "successful": 0,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 0,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

This is my index creation in opensearch.net:

```
        var createIndexResponse = await _client.Indices.CreateAsync("salesorders", c => c
            .Map<SalesOrder>(m => m
                .AutoMap()
                .Properties(ps => ps
                    .SearchAsYouType(s => s
                        .Name(n => n.OrderReference)
                    )
                    .SearchAsYouType(s => s
                        .Name(n => n.CustomerName)
                    )
                    .Nested<SalesOrderItem>(n => n
                        .Name(nm => nm.LineItems)
                        .AutoMap() // This will auto map the properties of SalesOrderItem
                        .Properties(pps => pps
                            .SearchAsYouType(s => s
                                .Name(nn => nn.ActiveIngredients)
                            )
                            .SearchAsYouType(s => s
                                .Name(nn => nn.ArticleDescription)
                            )
                            .SearchAsYouType(s => s
                                .Name(nn => nn.Sku)
                            )
                            .Number(n => n.Name(nn => nn.BackorderQuantity).Type(NumberType.Integer))
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );
```

And this is the index mapping within OpenSearch:

```
{
  "salesorders": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "created": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "customerName": {
          "type": "search_as_you_type",
          "doc_values": false,
          "max_shingle_size": 3
        },
        "customerNumber": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "customerReference": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "distributionChannel": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "division": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "erpOrderReference": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "invoiceCode": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "isFutureOrder": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "lineItems": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "activeIngredients": {
              "type": "search_as_you_type",
              "doc_values": false,
              "max_shingle_size": 3
            },
            "articleDescription": {
              "type": "search_as_you_type",
              "doc_values": false,
              "max_shingle_size": 3
            },
            "backorderQuantity": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "discountPercentage": {
              "type": "double"
            },
            "ean": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "expiryDate": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "incorrectOrderQuantityReceived": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "invoice": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "invoiceItem": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "invoiceNumber": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "isBackorder": {
              "type": "boolean"
            },
            "itemCascaded": {
              "type": "boolean"
            },
            "itemCategory": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "itemDiscountPercentage": {
              "type": "double"
            },
            "lineId": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "lineStatus": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "merchantCategory": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "netValue": {
              "type": "double"
            },
            "orderQuantity": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "prescriptionNumber": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "priceExclGst": {
              "type": "double"
            },
            "rejectionDescription": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "rejectionReason": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "sasbReference": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "sku": {
              "type": "search_as_you_type",
              "doc_values": false,
              "max_shingle_size": 3
            },
            "substitutedArticle": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "subtotalExclGst": {
              "type": "double"
            },
            "subtotalInclGst": {
              "type": "double"
            },
            "suppliedQuantity": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "userCancelled": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "orderReference": {
          "type": "search_as_you_type",
          "doc_values": false,
          "max_shingle_size": 3
        },
        "orderSource": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "orderStatus": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "orderType": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "paymentReference": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "promotionId": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "returnReason": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "returnReasonDescription": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "salesOrganisation": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "sapCreatedDate": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "sapCreatedTime": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "sourceReturnReference": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "sraRequestComments": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "supplierCode": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "totalDiscountAmount": {
          "type": "double"
        },
        "totalPrice": {
          "type": "double"
        },
        "totalPriceExclGst": {
          "type": "double"
        },
        "updated": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "userCreated": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It's unclear to me why the orderReference field is being complained about when it's not in my query. I am using this field as the document id, but I don't "think" that would cause this issue?

Comment: Are you sure that the error is for this query and you don't have multiple queries running at the same time?

Comment: I figured it out, the issue was that orderReference was being included in the sorting, which is added to the query after the point I was capturing it. However, despite solving that issue, I'm now facing the problem that despite specifying the orderReference as both search sa you type AND a key word sub field, the generated index PUT only specifies it as a search as you type field. :(

Comment: Glad you figured out the issue regarding sorting. There must be an issue with how you specify the s-a-y-t field and the keyword sub-field, because that should work.